# How to reverse an integer?

Tags: java, debugging, integer, reverse

I have a code to reverse an integer, but it does not work, can't seem to find the bug.

```java
public static void test(int N) {
    int enable_print = N % 10;
    while (N > 0) {
        if (enable_print == 0 && N % 10 != 0) {
            enable_print = 1;
        } else if (enable_print == 1) {
            System.out.print(N % 10);
        }
        N = N / 10;
    }
}
```

Comment: replace `else if` with `if`

Comment: does not work for input 12345
however it does work if you do ```if (enable_print >= 0)``` instead of the else if

Answer (score 1):

if and else if both works together in a sequence from top to down

if(true) { execute } else if() { done execute even if condition is true } else { done execute}

if(false) else if(check condition) { if true execute other wise go to next condition}

So on..

in your case, this is going to be solution

```java
public static void test(int N) {
    int enable_print = N % 10;
    while (N > 0) {
        if (enable_print == 0 && N % 10 != 0) {
            enable_print = 1;
        }

        if (enable_print == 1) {
            System.out.print(N % 10);
        }
        N = N / 10;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it is easier and/or better to rewrite instead of debugging.

Write or think of your algorithm in pseudocode where each high level step is then broken down into more pseudocode. Your conditions seem strange and therefore hard to debug.

It is best not to embed a print directly into the heart of a loop. Rather, build a string and return it.  Let the caller print a string.

```
System.out.println (reverseInt (12345));


public static String reverseInt (anInt) {
   Initialize a StringBuffer with an empty string.
   while (anInt > 0) {
      Get last digit by modulo 10 and put in StringBuffer.
      Prepend digit in StringBuffer.
      Chop off last digit by doing integer divide.
  }
  return StringBuffer's .toString ();
}
```

An alternate algorithm would call reverseInt recursively to build an ever growing string.